# unmount an external disk with no display - just keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, external-hard-drive, unmounting

My laptop screen isn't producing an image - damn floor hit my computer - though it seems to be working fine from the normal sounds (bootup, on board sound keys, purring... etc.)

My Timemachine has backed everything up and I would like to unmount my external rather than just unplug it.  All I have is the keyboard since I don't know where I'm clicking with the trackpad.

I don't have an external monitor and won't have access to one for a bit.  think "remote."

So does anyone know of a keyboard shortcut for unmounting a disk or all disks?

Answer (score 2):

ssh in and [`umount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/umount.8.html). Or open a terminal first if possible.

Comment: if i never enabled remote login on the ill laptop, can i still ssh in?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow get into `Finder`. Perhaps click at one of the screen edges (a few seconds of moving the pointer there will do), or use an application launcher (e.g. Quicksilver, LaunchBar). If you never disabled the keyboard shortcuts, press `Ctrl-F3` once to get Dock keyboard focus, then `Return`.

1. `Cmd-N` to open a new window
2. `Cmd-Shift-C` to get to top (machine) level
3. Press `Esc`, then type *Volume Name* once to get the desired entry
4. Press `Cmd-E` for *Eject*

If you have mounted disk images on external volumes, this might not work at all, they block ejecting.

If you don't know the volume name, replace steps 3 and 4 with:

1. Press `Esc`, then `Down` once to select the first list item.
2. Press `Cmd-E` for *Eject*
3. Select another list item by pressing `Esc` (clearing selection), then `Up` or `Down` once or more.
4. Repeat these steps a few times to unmount all volumes except the ones you cannot (i.e. *Network* item and your start volume)

---

Alternatively, find out your exact `umount` command and start `Terminal` using an application launcher, or by finding Finder like above, then pressing `Cmd-Shift-U` to open the `Utilities` folder, then type *Terminal* to locate the program, then `Cmd-Down` to start it.

---

If you have a launcher such as `Launchbar`, type your hotkey then "shutdown". Press enter and see if the machine gets turned off.

---

Close the lid to go to sleep. Not a dismount, but there shouldn't be any more disk activity.

---

Click the very top left of the screen to open the `Apple` menu (move the pointer for a few seconds there), or, if you didn't disable the keyboard shortcut, press `Ctrl-F2` then `Enter` to focus the menu bar, then open the Apple menu. Press `Up` twice, and then `Option+Enter`. This will shut down the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am off the mark here, but why not just shut the laptop down - either with the common keyboard shortcuts or even by just pressing the power button? When it is off, no program can have any handles on the drive, so it is safe to unplug it.